# one process waiting for another process's output via the file system

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a process A that reads in some data produced by some other process B. The data is 'exchanged' via the file system. To ensure that the file exists, process A currently checks for the file's existence like this:

```
while (!File.Exists(FileLocation))
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

This only seems to work 99 percent of the time. The other 1 percent of the time, process A establishes that the file exists but process B has not written everything yet (i.e. some data is missing).

Is there another simpler way to make the above situation more bullet proofed? Thanks.

Comment: Not really, although you should be using FileSystemWatcher (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) - but that won't help with your problem other than removing your polling. You'll have to wait until the file hasn't changed size for (insert appropriate number of seconds here). Hacky hacky.

Comment: Have you looked at FileSystemWatcher? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: Thanks I was looking into FileSystemWatcher but I do not think it would work in my situation.

Comment: Can you change the code for the other process, or is it impossible?

Comment: I can manage the code of both processes.

Comment: Ahh, in that case you can use a named mutex to communicate between the processes.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into this.

Comment: I've added a wee example as an actual answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another simpler way to make the above situation more bullet proofed?

You could use a [`Mutex`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Mutex) for reliable inter-process synchronization. Another possibility is to use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

After determining that the file exists, you can try opening the file for exclusive access, which will fail if another process still has the file open:

```
try
{
   File.Open("foo",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.None);
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
   // go back to 
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is the solution. Every time this fails, wait a second and then try it again. Eventually the other process will close the file, this will succeed, and you're good to go. It is dodgy, but unless you can change the other process to use proper signalling, this is the best you're likely to be able to do.

Comment: It's not ideal certainly, but I'm not sure you have much choice if you don't control the "producer" side as well.  If you do control the producer side, you could produce a 2nd file ("foo.lock") that will disappear once the write is complete, and you could check for both.

Comment: NOTE: The OP's most recent response indicates that he can change the code for both processes; given that information, a better solution is available. Your idea is best if the other process couldn't be changed though.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say that you can change both processes' code, you can use an EventWaitHandle to communicate between the processes.

In your program that creates the file, in the Main() method you can create an EventWaitHandle and keep it around until the end of the program. You'll need to pass the EventWaitHandle object around in your program so that it is available to the bit of code that creates the file (or provide some method that the file-creating code can call to set the event).

```
using (EventWaitHandle readySignaller = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "MySignalName"))
{
    // Rest of program goes here...
    // When your program creates the file, do this:

    readySignaller.Set();
}
```

Then have some code like this in the program that's waiting for the file:

```
// Returns true if the wait was successful.
// Once this has returned true, it will return false until the file is created again.

public static bool WaitForFileToBeCreated(int timeoutMilliseconds) // Pass Timeout.Infinite to wait infinitely.
{
    using (EventWaitHandle readySignaller = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "MySignalName"))
    {
        bool result = readySignaller.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds);

        if (result)
        {
            readySignaller.Reset();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

NOTE: If we successfully wait note that I am resetting the signal and it will remain reset until the other process sets it again. You can handle the logic differently if you need to; this is just an example.

Essentially what we are (logically) doing here is sharing a bool between two processes. You have to be careful about the order in which you set and reset that shared bool.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when
>   a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Comment: It does not work in my situation as I cannot catch events when I stop a sequential execution to wait for the file being completely written ... unless I miss something.